# Why can't I get items for the whole year using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I'm trying to get items which were published for the 2016. I use a simple query like that:

```
var buff = from p in data
           where p.Date >= Convert.ToDateTime("2016-01-01") 
                 && p.Date <= Convert.ToDateTime("2016-12-31")
           select new
           {
               p.Date,
               p.High,
               p.Low
           };
```

But it gives me only first 10 items. I got items which belong to may (yyyy-05-dd). Why my query stopped? How can I get the remaining items (yyyy-all months-dd)?

A part of **date**:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2016-05-06,49.919998,50.389999,49.66,50.389999,24715600,50.389999
2016-05-05,49.869999,50.299999,49.73,49.939999,25309500,49.939999
2016-05-04,49.84,50.060001,49.459999,49.869999,24171400,49.869999
2016-05-03,50.34,50.41,49.599998,49.779999,26196100,49.779999
2016-05-02,50.00,50.75,49.779999,50.610001,33004100,50.610001
2016-04-29,49.349998,50.25,49.349998,49.869999,48339700,49.869999
2016-04-28,50.619999,50.77,49.560001,49.900002,42758200,49.900002
2016-04-27,51.48,51.50,50.549999,50.939999,43145900,50.939999
2016-04-26,52.259998,52.349998,51.09,51.439999,33262300,51.439999
```

It's CSV file.

Comment: Have you checked the query for exceptions?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code (although the parsing of datetime is a bit of a code-smell, it still should work fine). It's likely there are only 10 items in the database, or you're filtering the query somewhere else.

Comment: You only published your query, not how you consume it. What happens if you write:   var temp = buff.ToArray();  and pause in a debugger? Still only get ten rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var buff = from p in data
           where p.Date.Year == 2016 
           select new
           {
               p.Date,
               p.High,
               p.Low
           };
```

Comment: Sorry, but I give the same result.

Comment: Look at my **date** I have added more information yet.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I found a mistake in my application. You answer was fully correct.

Comment: Good! i'am glad to hear it :)